# Car rental at 20 years old in UK

Tags: uk, car-rentals, age-limits

I am travelling to UK soon. I would like to hire a car during my stay. The problem is that I looked for almost all the major car rental agencies and all of them have an age restriction of 23 years old. I am only 20 and hold an International Driving Permit but has been driving since 18. Is there a way to find any agency that allows 20-year-olds rent a car?

Comment: You need to go for a very local 'mom-and-pop' rental company. These will be in the Home Counties with more certainty than in central London. Try Essex for example, that's where the one I use is located.

Comment: Definitely agree on trying smaller firms rather than the major rental agencies, though this can be a bit daunting when trying to book from overseas

Comment: Do you really need to rent a car? The UK has an excellent public transport system which reaches most places; unless you are going very far off the beaten track you may well be best using that. If you're just going to major cities, for example, a car will simply be an inconvenience.

Comment: As someone who has rented cars in the uk under the age of 23, be careful of companies which will take reservations over the internet, but do not charge you.  These companies can refuse the car rental when you arrive to pick up the car, or even charge you more money for a much smaller model.*ahem*Enterprise car hire*ahem*

Answer (score 9):

It is still possible to hire a car in UK with the age of 20  year. Answer is from  [Rental Car Age requirement](http://www.autoeurope.com/go/travel-tips/rental-car-age-requirements/):

[image]

The only concern is if you are able to find a car rental offering  a car for drivers with 20 years of age, the price might be too high. You also need to find a rental car company by yourself, here in TSE no one can guide you to find a agency which allows 20 year old to rent a car in UK.

> Is there a way to find any agency that allows 20-year-olds rent a car?

You may not have many options available to find major car rental companies who are willing to provide a car with the age of 20. However for eg [Yes Car Rentals For Young Drivers](http://yescarrentals.co.uk/index.php) may provide you a car with a heavy daily or weekly surcharge for a 20 year old driver.

And when we  make a booking for a car like Ibiza, Polo, Corsa and Fiesta with the age of 18 to 25, we get a price of 375 GBP for 1 week which is considerably very high compare to other rental car companies.

[image]

Therefore it is still possible to hire a car in UK with the age of 20 with higher rental fare if price is not an issue.

Comment: That answer isn't right.
Auto europe may claim that, but I've never seen a rental company offering hire cars to drivers that young, and neither can auto-europe's own search find one.

Comment: @CMaster check this website if it offer a rental car for driver under age 20. [Yes Car](http://yescarrentals.co.uk/index.php). Like I said we are not here to recommend websites regarding age 20 years old.

Comment: Your answer should at least guide the OP in to how to find the likes of Yes Car, seeing that is the specific question (they don't ask if it is possible, they ask how to find)